# In a .NET generic method, how to get the actual parameters type

Tags: .net, generics, methods, types, parameters

In a generic method, I want to know the type of the actual parameters passed. For example I have two classes:

```
class A {}
class B {}
```

Then a method taking any class as argument:

```
void M<T>(T instance)
{
    // how to tell what is the type of T if instance is null?
    // (so instance.GetType() won't work)
}
```

For example how to make a difference between the two following calls in the invoked method:

```
M<A>(null);
M<B>(null);
```

Is such a thing possible? The method `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` returns the generic method definition, not the actual generic arguments. Same thing for `StackTrace` frames.

Comment: `typeof(T)` gets you the type

Comment: I feel so stupid! (I'm getting used to, however). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof(T)` gets you the type.  Usually when I am in a generic class or method, this is the type that I want to base something on.

`instance.GetType()` gets the type of the instance but I may be looking for an implemented interface or a base class and `.GetType()` will never return that.  Also, as you pointed out, if you call `.GetType()` on a null, you will get a null reference exception.